# Access conditioned (with ngIf) DOM element in HTML template in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I'm trying to access a DOM element within my HTML template, but I got a problem : this element is conditioned with ngIf, and so I have the following error "Property 'drawer' does not exist on type 'Component'".

Here is an extract from my HTML code :

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav #drawer *ngIf="condition">
        ...
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content>
        <some-component (someEventEmitter)="drawer.open()"></some-component>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Is there a solution to call #drawer even if it is conditioned ?

I tried conditioning with "drawer ? drawer.open() : null" but I got the same error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The better way would be to hide it than using ngIf.

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav #drawer [hidden]="!condition">
        ...
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content>
        <some-component (someEventEmitter)="drawer.open()">
    </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

This should work

Also you can always not do things with drawer while it's not there

```
<mat-sidenav #drawer id="drawer" *ngIf="condition">
  ...
</mat-sidenav>
```

ts

```
const element: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('drawer') as HTMLElement;

if (element) {
  // do things with drawer
}
```

Comment: Yes it works but it triggers other problems. My condition is about the width of the screen, and in case of a resizing, sidenav stays open if it already was. Of course I can close it manually in this case, but I find that this solution isn't clean.

I guess it is possible to do what I want, as the Angular Material website does it.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Try this <mat-sidenav-container autosize="true">

Comment: Or if it doesn't work, maybe this will help: <mat-sidenav [fixedInViewport]="false">

Comment: So for the moment I use the "hidden" solution. Even if it can be cleaner, it works ! Thanks